Successful project being taken by higher ranking VP - feel demoralized
Just the title really; Successful project being taken by higher ranking VP and I'm being asked to go back to my regular duties - I feel completely demoralized.
Around Christmas, this huge gap was identified. I damn near killed myself to deliver a solution. It's working, it's functional, the tech involved is in my area of expertise.
I've long been a jack of all trades here, and when there is a gap, I fill it. I never really played the office politics game but this one feels especially egregious. In the past, I've always owned the solutions I developed fully. I expected this to be no different.
This solution I put together has the potential to be significant moving forward and having to document and hand off so some higher up can, in my view, replace / take credit feels just awful.
I don't know how to play my hand here. My manager is also being told to help me offload this to this new team.
I see dupes of this question, but I typed it all out and I'm just deflated, it was a huge amount of work.

Have you asked your manager or this VP why you are to hand this off to another group, and what was the answer? As far as we know, this may be a common occurrence.

" I've always owned the solutions I developed fully" - are you sure? I'm pretty sure your employer owns your work product.

Sometimes (not always), handing off a project becomes a layoff.  But the context for you might be quite different.

The assumption is that the VP is to STEAL your work. The reality is that the company values OP's work so much that a VP is LEADING the project. A project openly being handover is not theft.

You dutifully hand off the project, including documentation, as your manager has asked. Ask if you can be of further assistance, and check in with the VP periodically. Then, you enjoy the validation and success.
Passing off projects is a normal procedure--- different people/teams have different expertise. Your solution was so great that it was picked up by a team and has high enough priority for a VP. I haven't seen any reason to be down about this.

I appreciate the check, but you should wait for more answers before deciding.

Developing solutions, executing solutions, and supporting solutions are frequently executed by different departments in companies.  The larger the company, the more likely that jobs become more focused.
Think of this way.  If you are developing solutions and supporting solutions.  Eventually, the number of solutions you are supporting will consume so much time, that you can't develop solutions anymore. You, and your company, need to offload work that can be done by cheaper resources to other employees/departments.
Everyone has their own preferences for work environment, and each company has their preference on process.
If you prefer to continue to support the solution you have developed, you can always ask to move to a role that would enable that.  I would caution that you may like the compensation for what you do now more.
